# two structures of $\mathcal O_X$-Algebra for the sheaf of principal parts

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, tensor-products

Let $X \to S$ is be a morphism of schemes, and $F$ an $\mathcal  O_X$-modules.

Let $P=\mathcal O_X\otimes_{f^{-1}(\mathcal O_S)}\mathcal O_X$

I don't understand the following two structures of $\mathcal O_X$-Algebras, namely how we get $P \otimes F$ from $d_1$ and the $\mathcal O_X$-module structure with $d_0$

[image]

I can see the usage of $d_0$ in two ways:

- $d_1$ would map $\mathcal O_X$ to $P$ but in this case $P$ remains only partially an $\mathscr O_X$-module, it is exactly an $f^{-1}(\mathcal O_S)$-module, so we didn't form the tensor product over $\mathcal O_X$
- $d_1: a\to 1\otimes a$ would send $a\in \mathcal O_X$ to $F$ so it doesn't make sense.

The first way makes more sense to see $P$ as an $\mathcal O_X$- module and hence being able to for the tensor product over $\mathcal O_X$ but I don't see how

Thank you for your lights.

Comment: Basically $\mathcal{O}_X$ can act on $P$ by acting either on the left factor or the right factor. When you take $P\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} F$ you use the action of $\mathcal{O}_X$ on the right side to form the tensor product, and you use the action on the left side to act on $P\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} F$. At least this is what I understand from the text.

Comment: Thank you @CaptainLama, I understand. But how $d_1$ and $d_0$ come into play? Right action gives an $\mathcal O_X-$module $P$ so we can "form" $P\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} F$.  Then we wouldn't need $d_0$ anymore (the left action) as we can transfer all "scalars" of the action of $\mathcal O_X$  to F and use its $\mathcal{O}_X-$ module structure. is that right?

Comment: The above extract is from Berthelot's notes on crystalline cohomology

Comment: You should probably start by making sure you understand the affine case: take $R\to S$ a ring morphism and $M$ an $S$-module, define $P=S\otimes_R S$, and try to see how to form $P\otimes_S M$ as an $S$-module, using the action of $S$ on the right factor for the tensor product. You'll see that $P\otimes_S M\simeq S\otimes_R M$ has two natural $S$-module structures, and you want to use the one where $S$ acts on the left factor.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check the affine case